# Magento 2: what to do after changing product prices from an external app to have good data integrity?

Tags: magento2

I am working on a refectoring of an app from Magento 1 to Magento 2. The app changes product prices for Magento 2. I am doing this by invoking the object manager and using Magento 2 models.

Now my questions is. What do I have to do after I change prices in Magento 2? I am thinking of Caches, Indexes, Price rules etc?

For magento 1 we have below code

```
Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessByCode('catalog_product_price')->reindexEverything();    
Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessByCode('catalog_product_flat')->reindexEverything();

$resource = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalogrule/rule');
$resource->applyAllRulesForDateRange($resource->formatDate(mktime(0,0,0)));
Mage::app()->removeCache('catalog_rules_dirty');
```

What is the equivalent for Magento 2 and do I need to do additional things to have good data integrity?